# CKAN Organization Parameters

Tags: ckan

I created some parent/child relationships between some datasets to display a datasets tree with the ckanext-ord-hierarchy plugin.

By the way, because all these datasets belong to the same organization, this one show every datasets.
So I would like to only show datasets which aren't children of other ones (and so only show the first rank of the tree) in this organization.

Do someone know how to do it ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the child datasets you need to change the SOLR query done in package_search to add a filter. In your extension add a IPackageController and add the filter to the query in before_search().

The information as to whether it is a child should hopefully be in the package somewhere, but it might be squirrelled away and difficult to add a filter for. So it might be easier to have a separate SOLR field that says whether it is a child or not, calculated in a before_index() method of your IPackageController.